# How do I set the transaction fee in Multibit?

Tags: transaction-fees, multibit

I can't see any options in View > Preferences nor on the Send tab!

I can't find any results in a [DDG](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=multibit+transaction+fee) search!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The developers of Multibit have explicitly disabled such a feature to change the transaction fee, citing concerns that having little or very low transaction fees would result in the transaction taking too long to process (which is going to be unbearable for the average user only interested in sending and receiving money quickly).

From the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bitcoin-solutions/multibit/issues/23) originally submitted, the developer explains:

> The reason for this is that whilst in theory it is possible to send BTC with zero fee in practice it is not. For the "regular user" (i.e. someone who just wants to use bitcoin and does not really know the details) their user experience is quite poor with zero fee tx. We have probably both experienced this with Instawallet (zero fees added) where you sometimes have to wait until the next morning before the miners decide to add your tx to a block.
>
> It would create too much frustration to users (and too many support calls for me) to have zero fees.

Note: `tx` means a transaction.

Comment: Ack! I sent myself all my money from my Bitcoin QT wallet to MultiBit with 0 fee and it went through fine. I just feel it is wrong to have to pay a fee just to transfer money to yourself... to buy stuff seems ok.

Comment: Oops. I can understand the case for having defaults. But having no way to change the fee is just bad taste. I wish I knew about this limitation before I accepted BTC into my Multibit HD wallet...

Answer (score 2):

As of Multibit Classic 0.5.19 (last in the series) you can now do this. However, the max transaction fee ratio is too low for today's market and miners! If you want to spend out of this client, *even to [upgrade](https://multibit.org/help/hd0.4/how-to-upgrade-from-classic.html)* to another client, you'll need to do something like this:

## Compile a modified client

1. Clone the repo: `git clone git@github.com:keepkey/multibit.git multibit-classic; cd multibit-classic`
2. Check out the most recently released version: `git checkout v0.5.19`
3. Edit the max transaction fee in `src/main/java/org/multibit/viewsystem/swing/view/components/FeeSlider.java` from 50000 satoshis to something larger, e.g. 100000 (i.e. 1 mBTC).
4. Compile with Maven: `mvn -DskipTests=true package`
5. The executable is `target/multibit-exe.jar`

## Use the modified client

What I did was install [v0.5.19](https://multibit.org/release-info/classic/v0.5.19.html) the usual way, then swap out the multibit-exe.jar in the install directory for the modified one I made. You can *probably* just run the jar file directly, but I can't test that out at the moment.

Comment: "Are you telling me I'll be able to trade in my bitcoins for millions of dollars?" "No, in the future, you won't be able to."

Comment: Isn't MultiBit Classic 1.5 years old? Is there something wrong with MultiBit HD?

Comment: Unfortunately, the upgrade path to HD involves doing a sweep transaction, even [as of 0.4](https://multibit.org/help/hd0.4/how-to-upgrade-from-classic.html): You open both clients and spend all remaining coin from Classic into an address your HD has... which you can *no longer do* in today's market. There's no wallet import feature, which is utterly baffling. They even recommend you keep Classic around in case someone sends you more money! (I'd say there's something wrong with both, honestly.)

Answer (score 2):

I recently tried to modify the wallet but the maven build did not work because many of the google code repositories are now offline. What eventually worked for me was the following.

- Extracted the multibit-exe.jar from the latest OSX version of Multibit
- Used JD-GUI to decompile and extract FeeSlider.java
- Modified FeeSlider.java so I can enter larger transaction fees
- Recompiled using JDK 7 (JDK 8 didn't work) and adding multibit-exe.jar to the classpath
- Using 7Zip to replace the FeeSlider.class file in the jar file with my modified one

Replacing the multibit-exe.jar in the application with my modified one.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that it is not possible to tune fees with multibit.

If anyone knows a wallet where it is possible to do so, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The original Bitcoin wallet will let you set the fee manually.